# Induced sub graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am working on graph labeling problem. I want to know , Given two graphs G1 and G2, Is there any algorithm to check whether G1 is Induced subgraph of G2 ? Preferably polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: Does $G_2$ and $G_2$ are in any way related (e.g. share vertices or something)? For two arbitrary graphs with $|V(G_1)| = |V(G_2)|$ it becomes the [graph isomorphism problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem), so it is at least as hard in general setting.

Comment: or some other imposed structure, otherwise you could consider the sequence $G_1 = K_{|V(G_2)|}$, $G_1 = K_{|V(G_2)| - 1}$ and solve the maximal clique problem for $G_2$

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, in its full generality, it's an NP-complete problem since it contains the [clique problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), so it's not reasonable to expect a polynomial time algorithm in general.

If your candidate subgraph has some additional properties, such as being connected and having a bounded number of vertices, then you should be able to use the algorithm used by Grochow and Kellis for detecting [network motifs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_motif):

> J. A. Grochow and M. Kellis, [Network Motif Discovery Using Subgraph Enumeration and Symmetry-Breaking](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-71681-5_7), Lecture Notes in Computer Science 4453 (2007) pp. 92-106

If you're searching for a $k$-node subgraph in an $n$-node input network, in the worst case, it will inspect $\binom{n}{k}=O(n^k)$ $k$-node subgraphs.  But in practice, far fewer subgraphs will be inspected.

This might be regarded as a modified (or improved) version of Wernicke's ESU algorithm:

> S. Wernicke, Efficient detection of network motifs.  IEEE/ACM Transactions on Computational Biology and Bioinformatics, 3(4):347–359, 2006. ([pdf](http://theinf1.informatik.uni-jena.de/publications/motifs-tcbb06.pdf))

The ESU algorithm simply iterates through all $k$-node connected subgraphs, inspecting each such subgraph exactly once.

[gtrieScanner](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/gtries/) is a implementation of ESU algorithm for the motifs problem; it should be suitable for finding an individual subgraph as in this question.